# How to use an XML file to store data from a php query

Tags: php, mysql, xml

After moving from my earlier hosting server to a new one I realised that I can use only one database on my account. I am using that database for Wordpress for my website. I have a php quiz on my website which uses a mysql database to store just one table - users - which stores the first name, last name and email id of the quiz taker along with the date the quiz was taken and the answers selected for the 30 questions (which have 5 options each with different scores per answer and you can select only one of the 5).

Now since I can't use MySQL database, is there anyway I can use XML or any other format (I am on linux server) to store this data?

Comment: Why you can not user mysql database if you already have credential for that?

Comment: Why can't you store it in the same database you use for wordpress?

Comment: you can use the same database for both wordpress and quiz as long as table names do not conflict

Comment: Thanks Chanchal118, Barmar and JimiDini. I hadn't thought of that. It works.